# gnome-shell-extension: JS that works in looking glass doesn't in extension

Tags: javascript, gnome-shell-extension, looking-glass

I've got the following snippet of code that (in the looking glass) gives me a list of contacts I have (managed by gnome-contacts):

```
// METHOD 1:
const ContactDisplay = imports.ui.contactDisplay;
let csp = new ContactDisplay.ContactSearchProvider();
let contacts = csp.getInitialResultSet(['']);
contacts.length // 120 contacts

// METHOD 2:
const ContactSystem = Shell.ContactSystem;
let cs = ContactSystem.get_default();
let contacts2 = cs.initial_search(['']);
contacts2.length // 120 contacts
```

This two pieces of code are (as far as I know) equivalent, as `ContactSearchProvider`'s `getInitialResultSet` basically calls the `initial_search` method of `ContactSystem.get_default()`.

However, when I put these **same** bits of code into a gnome shell extension (say the `enable` method), and I `global.log(contacts.length)` or `global.log(contacts2.length)`, **I always get `0`**.

Hence for some reason this code works in looking-glass but *not* in an extension. Why is this? Are the contacts not loaded at the point the extension is executed? Is the contact search provider somehow not connected up to me? How can I work around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked this on the gnome-shell mailing list -- it turns out that the extensions are loaded quite early on in the piece, before the a user's contacts have properly been loaded.

Adding a 5-second delay to the code snippet that retrieves the contact list (to give the system a chance to load all the contacts) works a charm.

Comment: http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Too-Much-Sleep.aspx

Sleep for synchronization is a very poor solution.

Comment: sure, but can you suggest an alternative in this case? the relevant libraries do not provide signals indicating that contacts have loaded, so it's not like I can connect to the signal with a callback.

Comment: I have to say I never touched that part of the API, so I'm not sure. The hacky way would be finding some side effect of contact initialization and rely on that. For instance by monkey patching a function that is called by the initalization.